# UITableViewCell textLabel text wont set

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

have a UITableViewCell "postCell" that is an IBOutlet and is attached to a cell I have placed in my .xib. To set the text label:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

postCell.textLabel.text = @"TEXT";

}
```

Nothing ever appears.

Edit: This cell is not part of a Table View. Every answer I have seen is assuming it is. This is a single UITableViewCell.

Comment: Um. You set table cell content in UITableViewDatasource::cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section          {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:     (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";  
    PostCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[PostCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"text";
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Also add the `numberOfRows` method to complete the answer, without it, there won't be any cells ;)

Comment: Well, it is already been mentioned above UITableview's datasource method  cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

You can set text label for the cell in method cellForRowAtIndexPath, please see example below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Cell Title";

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few delegate methods that you need to implement.   Here are the two most important ones

```
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:
```

Here's a full tutorial on how to implement a table view.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/?p=1797